# type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Message, any[]>

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

Im trying to do a kendo chat example: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/conversationalui/
Im using visual studio code and angular 6 and I was searching in google but cant find a solution
But I got this error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(68,7): error TS2345: Argument of
>   type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'OperatorFunction'.   Types of parameters
>   'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>         Type 'Message' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
>           Property 'length' is missing in type 'Message'.

My component is it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { windowCount } from 'rxjs/operators/windowCount';
import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators/scan';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators/take';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators/tap';
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';

import { ChatModule, Message, User, Action, ExecuteActionEvent, SendMessageEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-conversational-ui';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ChatService } from './chat.service';

@Component({
  providers: [ ChatService ],
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <kendo-chat
        [messages]="feed | async"
        [user]="user"
        (sendMessage)="sendMessage($event)"
      >
      </kendo-chat>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public feed: Observable<Message[]>;

  public readonly user: User = {
    id: 1
  };

  public readonly bot: User = {
    id: 0
  };

  private local: Subject<Message> = new Subject<Message>();

  constructor(private svc: ChatService) {
    const hello: Message = {
      author: this.bot,
      suggestedActions: [{
        type: 'reply',
        value: 'Neat!'
      }, {
        type: 'reply',
        value: 'Thanks, but this is boring.'
      }],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      text: 'Hello, this is a demo bot. I don\t do much, but I can count symbols!'
    };

    // Merge local and remote messages into a single stream
    this.feed = merge(
      from([ hello ]),
      this.local,
      this.svc.responses.pipe(
        map((response): Message => ({
          author: this.bot,
          text: response
        })
      ))
    ).pipe(
      // ... and emit an array of all messages
      scan((acc, x) => [...acc, x], [])
    );
  }

  public sendMessage(e: SendMessageEvent): void {
    this.local.next(e.message);

    this.local.next({
      author: this.bot,
      typing: true
    });

    this.svc.submit(e.message.text);
  }
}
```

The line code where Im getting error is it:

```
scan((acc, x) => [...acc, x], [])
```

Comment: I am getting similar issue using `rxjs@^5.5` w/ `typescript@^3.1.1`. Getting error on same line: `Argument of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<any[]>, Observable<any[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<Message>, Observable<any[]>>'`

Comment: I fixed mine by changing `private local: Subject<Message> = new Subject<Message>();` to `private local: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the specific issue as well. Try the below fix:

```
scan((acc:any, x) => acc.concat(x), [])
```

See also: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2897#issuecomment-334654459